# GraphQL Resolver for Nested Array of Objects

Tags: schema, graphql, resolver

I am trying to get to grips with the GraphQL schema language as part of a work project. I'm running into problems I think because I'm not sure how to write the resolver for a particular data structure I need to use. I have some data for an appointment management system I am writing. There are at this point three collections - **Staff**, **Account**, and **Booking**. A simplified version of the typical json data looks like this:

```
Staff: {
    id: 0,
    Name: 'Joe Blogs',
    Speciality: 'Fitter'
}

Account: {
    id: 0,
    Name: 'Fred Foo',
    Company: 'Acme Holdings',
    staffId: 0
}

Booking: {
    id: 0,
    Date: '2018-03-23',
    staffId: 0,
    accountId: 0,
    AssignedStaff: [
        {id: 0, staffId: 1},
        {id: 1, staffId: 3}
    ]
}
```

So, a booking will relate to a particular account and be owned by a particular staff member. It will also have an arbitrary number of other staff assigned to it. My GraphQL schema looks like this:

```
type Staff {
    id: Int!
    Name: String!
    Speciality: String!
    accounts: [Account]
    bookings: [Booking]
}

type Account {
    id: Int!
    Name: String!
    Company: String!
    staff: Staff!
    bookings: [Booking]
}

type Booking {
    id: Int!
    Date: String!
    staff: Staff!
    account: Account!
    AssignedStaff: [AssignedStaff]
}

type AssignedStaff {
    id: Int!
    staff: Staff!
}
```

I have working resolvers for the relationships between **Staff** and **Account** and **Booking** working properly. Where I am having problems is with writing a resolver for the assigned staff on a booking. I am doing the development using static dummy data for the time being. The working resolver functions look like this:

```
Account: {
    bookings (account) {
        return booking.filter(booking => booking.accountId === account.id)
    },
    staff (account) {
        return staff.find(staff => staff.id === account.staffId)
    }
},
Booking: {
    account (booking) {
        return account.find(account => account.id === booking.accountId)
    },
    staff (booking) {
        return staff.find(staff => staff.id === booking.staffId)
    }
},
Staff: {
    accounts (staff) {
        return account.filter(account => account.staffId === staff.id)
    },
    bookings (staff) {
        return booking.filter(booking => booking.staffId === staff.id)
    }
}
```

and they work fine. I can do e.g. a query like this:

```
staff(id: 0){
    Name
    accounts {
        Name
        bookings {
            Date
        }
    }
}
```

and it works, the data returned is exactly what I expect. The problem arises when I try to return data about the assigned staff on a booking. I have a resolver for AssignedStaff which currently looks like this:

```
AssignedPhotographer: {
    staff(booking) {
        return staff.filter(staff => staff.id === booking.AssignedStaff.staffId)
    }
}
```

but when I run a query against it like this for instance:

```
staff(id: 0){
    Name
    accounts {
        Name
        bookings {
            Date
            AssignedStaff {
                staff{
                    Name
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The data I get back has an array of null values for AssignedStaff. The number of nulls matches the number of assigned staff for the booking, but it seemingly is not linking to the Staff type properly. If I just request the ids of the assigned staff for a booking like this:

```
staff(id: 0){
    Name
    accounts {
        Name
        bookings {
            Date
            AssignedStaff {
                id
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works ok and gives me back the correct data. I'm guessing that the problem is with the way I have done my resolvers, probably specifically with the AssignedStaff resolver. Can anybody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: staff.filter(staff => staff.id === booking.Photographers.staffId) should not be staff.filter(staff => staff.id === booking.staffId)?

Comment: Each booking has an owner staffId, and an arbitrary number of other AssignedStaff which both need to link to the same Staff data. I use staff.filter(staff => staff.id === booking.staffId) to resolve the link between the booking and the booking owner, and that works fine but I also need to get Staff data about the staff in the array of assigned staff. (edited question slightly so that all the field names match)

Answer (score 1):

You have any array of `Staff` objects that you filter and then try to return as an array of `AssignedStaff`. `Staff` and `AssignedStaff` do not share any fields except for `id` -- which is why you see the `id` field populated but not the `staff` field.

GraphQL is expecting an array like this:

```
[ { id, staff } ]
```

and you are passing it

```
[ { id, name, speciality } ]
```

You'll need to modify your resolver to look something like this:

```
return staff
  .filter(s => s.id === booking.AssignedStaff.staffId)
  .map(f => ({ id: f.id, staff: f }))
```

I don't know what (if any) the intended difference between AssignedStaff.id and AssignedStaff.staff.id is so you may need to fiddle with the above code but it should give you a starting point.

Comment: Hi Daniel,

This certainly gets me closer. I removed the id property from AssignedStaff so that it now just consists of the staffId to link it to the Staff type. I also bunged a console.log into the map function to see what 'f' is and it consists of a Staff type object for the correct AssignedStaff, however, though the query now returns a staff prop the Name within that is still null.

{
  "data": {
    "booking": {
      "Date": "2018-03-01",
      "AssignedStaff": [
        {
          "staff": {
            "Name": null
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}